# Using uint64_t to store a 18 digit number, why this code does not produce desired output

Tags: c++

This is a CSES problem, named number spiral [here](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1071), I know this is not the efficient way to do this, but it should however work, Can Someone explain to me why it's partially not working, I even tried the same thing with python its giving me `timelimitExceeded`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T; //no of test cases
    while(T--){
        uint64_t x, y; //I also tried using long long, but the output is same
        cin >> x >> y;
        if(x%2==0 && y%2!=0 && y< x){
            cout << fixed <<((x*x)-y)+1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2==0 && y%2!=0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)-x)+1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && y<x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)-x)+1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << ((pow((y*y)-1, 2))+x)-1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2==0 && y<x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)+x)-1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2==0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << (pow((y-1), 2))+x << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2!=0 && y<x){
            cout << fixed << (pow((x-1), 2))+y << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2!=0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)-x)+1 << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On input : 689913499 770079066 
result : 593021767041187712.000000 
instead of : 593021767041187724

Comment: Have you stepped through you code with a debugger?

Comment: I know that this specific output is coming from this 3rd last cout line (cout << fixed << (pow((y-1), 2))+x << "\n";)

Comment: _"I know this is not the efficient way to do this"_ - How do you know that you've not come to the same conclusion as everyone else, if your solution differs?

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Comment: fixed the ```include``` and ```namespace``` suggestion, thankyou ! [img](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/32259721?key=ddbfc212844db56af6847cf442fb9293)

Answer (score 5):

> Using uint64_t to store a 18 digit number

That is reasonable (even a 19 digit number would fit), but it's not what happened, what actually happened is that the `pow` calls convert the input to a `double` and also give their result as a `double`, and a 18-digit number does not quite fit in a double.

Changing the `pow` calls to a proper integer square fixed the problem for me, at least for this input.

For example:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

uint64_t square(uint64_t x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T; //no of test cases
    while(T--){
        uint64_t x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        if(x%2==0 && y%2!=0 && y< x){
            cout << fixed <<((x*x)-y)+1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2==0 && y%2!=0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)-x)+1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && y<x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)-x)+1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << ((square((y*y)-1))+x)-1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2==0 && y<x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)+x)-1 << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2==0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << (square((y-1)))+x << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2!=0 && y<x){
            cout << fixed << (square((x-1)))+y << "\n";
        }else if(x%2!=0 && y%2!=0 && y>x){
            cout << fixed << ((y*y)-x)+1 << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result was 593021767041187724, as seen on [ideone](https://ideone.com/rnjRQZ).

By the way, including `bits/std++.h` and `using namespace std` are both generally non-recommended.

Comment: General rule of thumb: when working with integers avoid `pow`. `pow` is a tool built to handle tricky cases like e to the power of pi, so using it to square numbers can be vast overkill. Many compilers and libraries will optimize simple cases, but usually it's just better to multiply. Also note that not even all small numbers can be properly computed. I've seen cases where `int x = 5; x = pow(x,2);` results in an `x` of 24 because pow spat out a close-enough for `double` 24.99999999999999 which gets truncated to fit it in an `int`.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question.@harold @user4581301

Comment: @KLAUS harold answered it. I just posted an addendum.